# CUDA support in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, graphics, gpu, cuda

I do not want to switch between cards.  Install CUDA card (GT 420 48 cores), and the motherboard disables the ATI video on the desktop computer, so CUDA is the exclusive driver of the display. There will not be need for multiple monitors.

1. Will it be recognized and can it be configured to match my monitor (1600x900)?
2. Do I need to locate drivers, if so where?
3. Can applications like BOINC access the GPU functions of the CUDA card?

Answer (score 1):

I have experience with CUDA using a GT 520, and there are no problems at all. You can just install the drivers Ubuntu suggests to you. According to [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1131430) forum, boinc will work as well.